# Два века спустя. "Спустя" —деепричастие или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Кажется, что в предложении ***А знаете, Александр Сергеевич, насколько актуальны и два века спустя Ваши эпиграммы?*** не хватает знака препинания в районе "спустя".

Нужно выделить "и два века спустя"?

Answer (score 4):

Спустя - не деепричастие, это предлог со значением "по прошествии чего-то, какого-то времени". Спустя два века - по прошествии двух веков.Никаких запятых нет.

Answer (score 3):

**СПУСТЯ, предлог (на основе деепричастия),**  по прошествии какого-л. времени. С. час двинулись дальше. С. несколько месяцев мы встретились снова.

**А знаете, Александр Сергеевич, насколько актуальны и два века спустя Ваши эпиграммы?**

Сравнить: А знаете, Александр Сергеевич, насколько актуальны и сейчас, **два века спустя**, Ваши эпиграммы?

Обычно обстоятельственные обороты с этим предлогом **не обособляются.** Обособление возможно в некоторых случаях, которые являются общими для всех производных предлогов: **а)распространенность оборота и удобная для обособления позиция; б) уточняющее значение по отношению к временному наречию.**

Примеры:

В современном обществе, **спустя считанные десятилетия после гибели Мандельштама,** пропасти этой, как известно, не существует вовсе. [Антон Носик. Самиздат, Интернет и профессиональный читатель // «Отечественные записки», 2003]

Ведь иногда жизнь действительно должна быть запечатленной и **потом, спустя много лет**, с гордостью или сожалением показана следующим поколениям...

**Сегодня, спустя несколько лет**, оригинальная ресторанная сеть насчитывает более 100 заведений в Великобритании, плюс рестораны в Нью-Йорке, Токио и Гонконге.